# Unit testing Chakra UI with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Currently I am trying to unit test my application that is built with Create-React-App with typescript, and it is styled with chakraui. Chakrui includes a component ThemeProvider that must wrap the entire application as such.

This is my index.tsx file

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { ThemeProvider, CSSReset } from "@chakra-ui/core/dist";
import { theme } from "@chakra-ui/core/dist";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CSSReset />
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

For every unit test that I write, I am having to wrap the component with ThemeProvider for the test to pass:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@chakra-ui/core/dist";

import App from "./App";

describe("<App />", () => {
  test("smoke test", () => {
    render(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  });
});
```

But this is very verbose, and must be done for *every* test that I write. Is there a way to do this just once in each `.test.tsx` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create your own theme wrapper function

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@chakra-ui/core/dist";

export const ThemeWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
);
```

And then specify the wrapper in the test

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ThemeWrapper } from "../testUtils";

import App from "./App";

describe("<App />", () => {
  test("smoke test", () => {
    render(<App />, { wrapper: ThemeWrapper });
  });
});
```

This marginally reduces the code for testing. You may be able to also go the route of creating a custom render function (following the steps for [redux](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux)).

It could look something like

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@chakra-ui/core/dist";

export const renderWithTheme = ui => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  );

  return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper });
};
```

Basically the same as the wrapper above, but more integrated into a test render function. You can adjust the function signature a bit as well if you need to pass in a theme object, or other render options, this is just a simple example.

Now the test looks like

```
import React from "react";
import { renderWithTheme } from "../testUtils";

import App from "./App";

describe("<App />", () => {
  test("smoke test", () => {
    renderWithTheme(<App />);
});
```

Comment: Woah! This is great. What is the ui prop for in renderWithTheme for?

Comment: @RedSkyHarbor That isn't a prop, it's the component being rendered/tested, was just following redux's name convention from their testing docs.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that Jest might be **mocking your imports** from `@chakra-ui/core/dist` (depending on your [jest configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html))  which might be resulting your imported chakra-ui components to be *undefined*.

Importing the *Theme Provider* and **wrapping it everytime** with your renders might be one way to do it. The problem might arise when you have **multiple components** in your `index.tsx`. So, you might not want to import each and every component.

In that case, you will want to import the **actual** components from *@chakra-ui/core*.

The best way (according to me) to do so in Jest is:

```js
jest.mock("@chakra-ui/core", () => {
    const ui = jest.requireActual("@chakra-ui/core");
    return {
        ...ui,
        customKey: 'customValue',
    };
})
```

This way you can even add **custom function and key-values** to the imported module.