# Jest Error Testing React Components Built with Chakra UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I would like to test my React components built with TypeScript and Chakra UI using React Testing Library and Jest, and I am building a wrapper component pretty similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855604/unit-testing-chakra-ui-with-jest). The difference is I am supplying a custom `theme.js` as a prop like so:

```
import React from "react"
import { render, RenderResult } from "@testing-library/react"
// @ts-ignore
import theme from "../../theme.js"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@chakra-ui/core"

export const renderWithTheme = (ui: React.ReactElement): RenderResult => {
    const Wrapper: React.ComponentType = children => <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>

    return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper })
}
```

Unfortunately this give me the following error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    Details:

    /Users/neilchaudhuri/Vidya/applications/c1ds/components/theme.js:7
    export default {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      2 | import { render, RenderResult } from "@testing-library/react"
      3 | // @ts-ignore
    > 4 | import theme from "../../theme.js"
        | ^
```

I am not sure why this happens since the theme file is definitely JavaScript.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: what you see if  remove // @ts-ignore ?

Comment: `TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../../theme.js'. '/components/theme.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: so add this file to `tsconfig.json` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Where? I've tried in `include` and have the same issue

Comment: in section `files`

Comment: I tried `"files": ["./theme.js"]` and `"files": ["theme.js"]` but sadly both produced the same

Comment: do you have `tsconfig.jest.json` file?

Comment: can you send project with minimal code and all config files via github or codesanbox?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60715689/1870780?